# Hide a Window with Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell, window, hide

I want to use the windows Powershell scripts to hide the Windows 7 taskbar or start button.
In Delphi it would be working like this for example:"ShowWindow(FindWindow('windowhandle'), SW_HIDE);". Is something like this possible in PowerShell? I already found modules for that but would there be a way to do it directly? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you count this 'directly', but you can call WinApi from PowerShell.

```
$definition = @"    
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

      public static void Show(string wClass, string wName)
      {
         IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(wClass, wName);
         if ((int)hwnd > 0)
            ShowWindow(hwnd, 1);
      }

      public static void Hide(string wClass, string wName)
      {
         IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(wClass, wName);
         if ((int)hwnd > 0)
            ShowWindow(hwnd, 0);
      }
"@

add-type -MemberDefinition $definition -Namespace my -Name WinApi

[my.WinApi]::Hide('Notepad', 'Untitled - Notepad')
```

I couldn't get it to work with Windows start button (it just disables), but it works with normal windows.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. With [my.WinApi]::Hide('Button', 'Start'), it gets smaller but not hidden...Any Ideas?

Comment: Btw: The whole taskbar leaves with: [my.WinApi]::Show('Shell_TrayWnd', '')

Comment: It appears there's no easy way to do it in Windows 7. Looks like besides start button, there is a picture on taskbar and you can't hide it [link](http://forums.realsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=40187).

Comment: Seems like that. I saw it once done from others but nor exactly how to do it. Well thanks anyways.